# Exchange 2010 Mail stuck in Queue - HUB Version 15 - Journaling

Tags: email, exchange-2010, spam

I have issues with my queue on my Exchange 2010 Hub Transport server. When I do a `Get-Queue`, I can see over 1000 emails on queue and the next hop is Hub Version 15! I don't have a clue what a Hub Version 15 is!

Here is what I get when I do a `Get-Queue`:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>get-queue

Identity                                 DeliveryType Status MessageCount NextHopDomain
--------                                 ------------ ------ ------------ -------------
Mail01\16                                SmtpRelay... Con... 1077         hub version 15
Mail01\Submission                        Undefined    Ready  0            Submission
```

When I look on at the emails in queue, this is what I see when i go the properties - General:

```
Identity: Mail01\16\7116
Subject: Incident 13639 has been raised
Internet Message ID: <64a52681-4699-44bc-88ae-35a65cb8348b@journal.report.generator>
From Address: <>
Status: Ready
Size (KB): 3
Message Source Name: Journaling
Source IP: 255.255.255.255
SCL: 0
Date Received: 4/16/2014 9:00:12 AM
Expiration Time: 
Last Error: 
Queue ID: Mail01\16
Recipients:  Journal@XXX.com;2;3;;0;CN=Journaling Database,CN=Databases,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=XXX,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=XXX,DC=XXX
```

and under recipient information

Journal@XXX.com with Status Ready and nothing on Last Error.

I dont have any email address with Journal@XXXX.com in my exchange, I have a Journal DB and only 1 DB has the Journal enable and it is pointing to the Journal DB.

Any idea on how to resolve this issue? I had to recreate the mail.que in order to start getting emails but the queue continues growing and all these messages have the Message source Name - Journaling and pointing to the same Queue ID Mail01\16.

Thanks!

Comment: Correction, I do have the Journal@XXX.com, I overlook.

Comment: *UPDATE* Email is working internally and externally, no issues, but my queue keeps growing and growing, all messages are from The message source name Journaling